# How to stop all instances of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm developping a socket-based game in Java about riddles in a competitive way.

The server program creates a response thread besides other threads for each player (client), what I want to do is stop (or interrupt) all those response threads once a player sends the right response.

Here's my code

```
public class testReponse implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String reponse="";

    public testReponse(Socket socket2){
            socket = socket2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!reponse.equals("right")){
            try {
                in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                String reponse = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Reponse : "+ reponse);

                if(reponse.equals("right")){    
                    out.println("correct");
                    out.flush();
                } else {
                    out.println("incorrect");
                    out.flush();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear where is your server code is. However, the way I would do it is by having an `AtomicBoolean` as an instance variable in the server code. Once the "right" message is received from any of the clients, the value would change to false. In the code in the server side if you see that the value is false, then you stop!

This is one way to go about it but there might be better ways to do it though.

```
public class MyServer {
    private AtomicBoolean keepServerOn = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public void setKeepServerOff() {
        keepServerOn.set(false);
    }

    public void shouldKeepGoing() {
        return keepServerOn.get();
    }

    public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    ....// where you accept clients and create TestResponse
    MyServer myServer = new MyServer();
    ...// somewhere new TestResponse(socket, myServer);
    }
}


public class testReponse implements Runnable {
private MyServer server;
private Socket socket;
private AtomicBoolean keepServerOn = new AtomicBoolean(true);

public testReponse(Socket socket2, MyServer server){
        socket = socket2;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        while(server.shouldKeepGoing()){
            String reponse = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Reponse : "+ reponse);

            if(reponse.equals("right")){    
                server.setKeepServerOff();
                out.println("correct");
                out.flush();
            } else {
                out.println("incorrect");
                out.flush();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(out!= null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```